# Linear Layout with an border

Tags: android

Can Any one help me to acheive the following border for an Linear layout.[image]

I can draw the border by shape, but donot know how to draw a pointed tooltip like which points to the Textview "seminar".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle"> 
 <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
 <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
        android:angle="225"/> 

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Any help please.

Regards,
Asmita

Comment: its a drawable, so just draw it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Android does not have any shape to do that. You need to define an image with that appearance and with the remaining background transparent.
Then you just have to define the background of your layout with your drawable.

Don't forget the different Android screens sizes and resolutions..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nine patch file, details on how to do nine patch files at: https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-9-patch-image-files. Generate a nine patch file and set it as the background drawable for the layout.

[image: Draw 9 Patch Utility]

In Use:

[image: Example In Use]